# How to compare IntegerChoice values in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-filter

I intend to compare the value of an IntegerChoice inside Django Template :

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Answer(models.IntegerChoices):
        NO = 0, _('No')
        YES = 1, _('Yes')
    
        __empty__ = _('(Unknown)')
    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=Answer.choices)

SomeModel.objects.create(answer=0)
somemodel = SomeModel.objects.filter(answer=0)

Inside template :

{% if somemodel.answer == SomeModel.Answer.YES %}
    ...
{% else %}
    <h1>{{ somemodel.get_answer_display() }}</<h1>
{% endif %}
```

Yet, this does not get inside the true if case, and also does not like "()" at the end of "SomeModel.get_answer_display" with the following message :

```
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'SomeModel.get_answer_display()'
```

Inside view:

```
class BrowseView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'))
    def get(self, request):
        somemodel = SomeModel.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'browse/index.html',
                      {
                       'somemodel': somemodel
                      })
```

How can I make the filter work as expected?

Comment: Remove the `()` so `SomeModel.get_answer_display`, Django template language supports limited syntax in an effort to separate business logic from presentation logic. The template engine will automatically call methods assuming they don't take any arguments

Comment: `somemodel` is a QuerySet not an _instance_ of `SomeModel` hence `somemodel.get_answer_display` does not make much sense unless there is a loop which you don't show in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In templates you do not call a function: in case something is a callable, Django will call the callable with no parameters, you thus render this with:

```
{% if somemodel.answer == SomeModel.Answer.YES %}
    …
{% else %}
    <h1>{{ somemodel.get_answer_display }}</<h1>
{% endif %}
```

You should also work with a model *object*, so `somemodel`, not <s>`SomeModel`</s>.

In your view, you will need to pass both the `somemodel` *object* and a reference to the `SomeModel` *class*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BrowseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    
    def get(self, request):
        somemodel = SomeModel.objects.all()
        return render(
            self.request,
            'browse/index.html',
            {'somemodel': somemodel, 'SomeModel': SomeModel}
        )
```

Here `somemodel` is also *not* a model object, it is a `QuerySet` (a collection) of `SomeModel`s. You thus should enumerate over these:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BrowseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'

    def get(self, request):
        somemodels = SomeModel.objects.all()
        return render(
            self.request,
            'browse/index.html',
            {'somemodels': somemodels, 'SomeModel': SomeModel}
        )
```

and in the template enumerate over the collection:

```
{% for somemodel in somemodels %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: somemodel.get_answer_display still gives me the numeric value, do you think that I might be doing something wrong ?

Comment: @SuperEye: can you edit the question and show the corresponding view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the model doesn't really need to be passed we can simply access that through the instance itself `somemodel.answer == somemodel.Answer.YES` (Have used something similar before)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, your suggestion makes great sense, and provides a convenient way to use the enums through the object. If you provide that as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @SuperEye no need to post multiple answers when there already is one (A good and working one that is) ;)

Comment: Yes, that is true. Agreed. Your suggestion also helped a lot. And finally thanks to @WillemVanOnsem for principal help.